# How to check calendar event exist or not in office 365 using c#?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, office365

Actually my requirement is when i push the calendar event to office 365, it want to insert into office 365 calendar,suppose already same date and time exit the event,it no need to insert,this following requirement i need offline user(means i don't have user password, i have only user office 365 email), is it possible to check the event in offline?

thanks,
karthik.

Answer (score 0):

REST API can obtain all the events of a user, but it is hard to check whether there is an event in a specified time duration. 
If you want to look for a way to get the get free/busy information of a user. you could try to use EWS Managed API:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn643673(v=exchg.150).aspx